# Trying to make a select list for product category upload in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, codeigniter-3

I'm making a website so users can add products to the website. On the form where users can add a certain product I'm trying to make a select dropdown bar so users can select a certain category that belongs to a product but I'm not sure how I can do that..

```
    Database info:
    category table: categories
    Rows in the category table: 
    1.  id
    2.  name
In my products table I also have a row called: category_id
```

This is my db helper file (db_helper.php) :

```
<?php if (!function_exists('get_categories_h')) {
    function get_categories_h(){
        $CI = get_instance();
        $categories = $CI->Product_model->get_categories();
        return $categories;
    } } ?>
```

This is the my Product_model file where I made the get_categories function:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Product_model extends CI_model {

    public function saveProduct($data) { 
        $this->db->insert('products', $data);
        $product_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $product_id;
    }
    public function get_product_details($product_id) {
        $arrReturn = array();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $arrReturn = $result[0];
        }
        return $arrReturn;
    }
    /*
      Get categories
     */
    public function get_categories(){
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('categories'); 
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

This is my view form where I'm trying to make the option select bar of the categories:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('Product/upload'); ?>
    <table class="aanbieding-cadeau">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'product_naam', 'name'=>'product_naam', 'placeholder' => '1. Naam van het cadeau', 'size'=>25));?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
                <select name="category">
                    <a href="#"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a> 
                </select>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo form_input(array('id'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'name'=>'ophaal_plaats', 'placeholder' => '3.Kies een stad', 'size'=>25));?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="">Gebruik adres van mijn account</label>
        </div>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h4>Upload foto</h4>
                <input type="file" name="userfile" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo form_textarea(array('type'=>'textarea','id'=>'product_beschrijving', 'name'=>'product_beschrijving', 'placeholder' => '5. Vertel iets over dit cadeau..', 'size'=>25));?>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Cadeau aanbieden!" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

When I load the view form I don't see one dropdown category option menu but I see 10 small selectbars that are empty when you click on them. ( PS: I have inserted 10 categories to my database)

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
<?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
    <select name="category">
        <a href="#"><?php echo $category['name']; ?>
        </a> 
    </select>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

you have put the `select` tag inside the loop, and `a` tag is not the part of `select`. Only put the `option` inside the loop and exclude the `select` from loop.

Change the code to:

```
<select name="category">
<?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
    <option><?php echo $category['name']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Also, do you maybe now how I can get my  category_id row inserted when you select a category?

Answer (score 2):

Change your select tag code to  :

```
 <tr>
  <select name="category">
      <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>

         <option ><?php echo $category['name']; ?></option> 

       <?php endforeach; ?>
   </select>
  </tr>
```

Note:

1)`Select` tag must be out side of loop.

2)  use `option` with select tag not `anchor`**